# How to set upload_tmp_dir in Plesk

Tags: plesk

I was trying to set upload_tmp_dir variable for one of my domain I added following entries

root@host1 /var/www/vhosts/vw-forum.pl/conf # cat vhosts.conf
 php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /tmp

Then I refreshed configuration

/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain vw-forum.pl

but in the end in php info it`s showing

upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value

Pls advice how to fix this..

Comment: What is the Plesk version?

Answer (score 1):

I have find out an answer it should be changed in PLesk Panel for particula domain
PHP settings tab for domain As "Additional configuration directives"

Comment: What if an "Additional configuration directives" link or field does not exist? Is that only available to certain Plesk versions? (mine is Plesk Onyx 17.8.11)

Answer (score 0):

My phpinfo also shows no value in `upload_tmp_dir`. However, as I've learned today from the error logs, you have to manually configure Plesk to accept that respective dir in the `open_basedir` PHP setting.

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (…)

I have just done so and can upload fine now, even though phpinfo still shows no value for that entry.